# Runtime in ArcPy versus ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcpy, raster, watershed, flood, code-review

I have at least two hundred huge TIFF rasters that I'm trying to process into floodplain polygons. They are cursory flood depth rasters for pluvial, fluvial and coastal flooding.

First, I need to set all values <.5 to null. However, when running these ArcPy scripts its slow and creates a large interim SetNull file in file explorer. It also takes a significant amount of time using ArcPy in comparison to using the geoprocessing tools in ArcGIS Pro

```
import os, arcpy
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *
arcpy.env.parallelProcessingFactor = "100%"
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

# Define workspace
arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\Fathom\00_Source_Data\Region1\Test"
out_gdb = r"C:\Fathom\Fathom.gdb"

print('Getting started')

# List of the rasters in the workspace
rasters = arcpy.ListRasters()

try:
    # Loop through the list of rasters
    for raster in rasters:
        # Get name (i.e. n33w99_P out of n33w99_2020_0p50_P_1in100.tif)
        prefix = raster.split("_")[0] + "_" + raster.split("_")[3]
        print(prefix)

        # Calculate statistics for the null raster
        print("Calculate stats:")
        arcpy.CalculateStatistics_management(raster)
        print(arcpy.GetMessages())  

        # Perform SetNull operation for any values less than .5 to remove unnecessary coverage
        print("Set null:")
        outSetNull = SetNull(raster, raster, "value < 0.5")
        print(arcpy.GetMessages())

        # Set the path for the null raster
        null_name = f"{prefix}_Null"
        null_raster_path = os.path.join(out_gdb, null_name)

        # Save the output null raster
        outSetNull.save(null_raster_path)
        print(f'Saved {null_raster_path}')
        print(arcpy.GetMessages())

        # Optionally, delete the original raster
        arcpy.Delete_management(raster)
        print(f'Deleted original raster: {raster}')
        print(arcpy.GetMessages())
        
except Exception as e:
    print(f"An unexpected error occurred: {str(e)}")
print('All done!')
```

Next I need to mosaic all the rasters that start with the same prefix before the first underscore in the file name (i.e. n33w99 for the pluvial, fluvial and coastal rasters that cover the same tile extent).

Then it should be reprojected to bring it into compliance with another similar dataset before I convert it to a floodplain polygon.

```
import os
import arcpy
arcpy.env.parallelProcessingFactor = "100%"

# Set folder path containing the rasters
arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\Fathom\Fathom.gdb"

# Get a list of all files in the folder
rasters = arcpy.ListRasters()

# Create a dictionary to store the raster groups
raster_groups = {}

# Loop through each file in the folder
for raster in rasters:
    # Get name (i.e. n33w99 out of n33w99_2020_0p50_P_1in100.tif) 
    prefix = file_name.split("_")[0]
    # Check if the prefix already exists in the dictionary
    if prefix in raster_groups:
        raster_groups[prefix].append(os.path.join(arcpy.env.workspace, raster))
    else:
        raster_groups[prefix] = [os.path.join(arcpy.env.workspace, raster)] 

# Loop through each raster group and perform mosaic operation
for prefix, raster_group in raster_groups.items():
    # Set output path and filename for the mosaic raster
    mosaic_out_name = f"{prefix}_Mosaic"
    mosaic_out_path = arcpy.env.workspace
    print(mosaic_out_name)
    coordinate_system = "4326"
    pixel_type = "32_BIT_FLOAT"
    cellsize = 0.0000308641975308642
    number_of_bands = 1 
    mosaic_method = "MAXIMUM"
    # Try and save to memory then save final raster to gdb?
    arcpy.MosaicToNewRaster_management(raster_group, mosaic_out_path, mosaic_out_name, coordinate_system, pixel_type, cellsize, number_of_bands, mosaic_method)
    print("Mosaic:")
    print(arcpy.GetMessages())
    arcpy.CalculateStatistics_management(os.path.join(mosaic_out_path, mosaic_out_name))
    print("Calc Stats:")
    print(arcpy.GetMessages())
    
    # Reproject mosaic raster
    out_coor_system = arcpy.SpatialReference(6588)  # WKID for the desired coordinate system
    reprojected_raster_name = f"{prefix}_Reprojected"
    reprojected_raster_path = os.path.join(out_path, reprojected_raster_name)
    arcpy.ProjectRaster_management(os.path.join(mosaic_out_path, mosaic_out_name), reprojected_raster_path, out_coor_system)
    print("Reprojection completed for:", reprojected_raster_name)
    print(arcpy.GetMessages())
    
    for file_name in file_list:
        arcpy.Delete_management(file_name)
        print(f'Deleted null raster: {file_name}')
        print(arcpy.GetMessages())
    
print("All done!")
```

With all that said, is there some way to optimize my scripts to make them quicker?

Comment: Optimizing a workflow/analysis is an interative process of identifying the bottleneck and resolving it and then finding the next bottleneck and resolving it and so on.  Do some timing of different parts of the script to find the slowest step or tool.

Answer (score 1):

I would say your first script is perfect for parallelising as no processing of a raster relies on any other dataset. You need to explore the python [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) module. There are numerous sites and discussions on forums such as this one and [esri community](https://community.esri.com/) in how to use arcpy in multiprocessing.

A small quick win is that the [Delete](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/delete.htm#GUID-6CC20A7A-337F-4B30-84C9-923567D5EB2B) tool can take lists of datasets to delete, why call it on every loop when a single call can be done after the loop?

Do you actually need to call Calculate Statistics BEFORE you set the pixels to NULL? I thought that would need to be done after you create the raster?

A side note for your second script, the setting of your parameters that are to be used in MosaicToNewRaster should not be within the loop, they only need to be set once BEFORE the loop.